# Should the word "must" be deleted?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> "Either you must grant his request or incur his wrath."

I suppose the *must* word should be deleted to make it grammatically correct?

Comment: "*You must either* grant his request or incur his wrath." is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Davo  better writing style, yes, but not necessarily more natural.  People talk like that all the time, especially when they're not thinking ahead to what sounds best.

Comment: “You must either grant …” is better (as @Davo says). You could omit it but the word “must” emphasizes that these are the only two choices (in contrast to “You *may* either grant …”)

Comment: I agree with @smatterer – the word "must" should be **moved**, not deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the word "**must**" the sentence sounds as though a direct order is given *(masks the right to choose)*:

- Either you grant his request or *(you'll)* incur his wrath. *(If you don't do it something bad is going to happen to you)*

With "**must**" included the sentences is less strict but still with obligation:

- Either you must grant his request or incur his wrath. *(You have a choice either **to grant his request** or **to incur his wrath**)*

As **@Davo** commented a more idiomatic way of saying it is:

- You must either grant his request or incur his wrath.